# RVIZ: Efficient way to display large, incremental 2D images in 3D space

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

as the title states, I am looking for an efficient way to display a large, incrementally growing, high resolution image in 3d space in RVIZ. Any suggestions?

My project partner are currently rendering every image on a seperate rectangle, which seems to be working. However it is eating the RAM for breakfast, which is not ideal.

Best regards,

Alex

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276902/rviz:-efficient-way-to-display-large,-incremental-2d-images-in-3d-space/) by [Laxnpander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29981/laxnpander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_textured_quads (See also #q22730).

How high is your resolution and frame rate?

When you say incrementally growing do you mean that you'd like to transmit smaller images that update a larger image (like costmap updates) rather than retransmitting the entire image every frame?  It probably wouldn't be too hard to make a version of rviz_textured_quads that can work like that.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laxnpander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29981/laxnpander/) on 2017-11-29**:
Yes, that is what I mean! Resolution can be up to several megapixels I guess, but framerate is quite low. Maybe round about ~1 Hz. Graphics card is available.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-11-29**:
Several megapixels at 1 fps doesn't sound too bad for rebroadcasting the full image, inefficient as it may be.

**Comment by [Laxnpander](https://answers.ros.org/users/29981/laxnpander/) on 2017-11-29**:
Ah, no that was a little misguiding. I have a stream of images that are mapped into a common reference plane. Every single image has 1 Mpix and comes with 1 FPS. The total map however is therefore at least 1 Mpix but can grow up to way beyond that.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-11-29**:
I see- even with a costmap update style approach the rviz end might break down with such a huge texture.  It would maybe need to be turned into tiles.